# asyncio.create_task decorator doesn't execute concurrently

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-decorators

I have having some trouble understanding asyncio's create_task function. From the documentation, tasks should be run concurrently when they are awaited. I wrapped the async func in a deocrator so I don't have to create_task() for every async function. But the concurrent execution fails

```
  import asyncio
  import time


  def async_task(func):
      def wrapper():
          return asyncio.create_task(func())
      return wrapper


  @async_task
  async def bar() -> int:
      await asyncio.sleep(3)
      return "hello"


  @async_task
  async def foo() -> int:
      await asyncio.sleep(3)
      return "world"


  async def main() -> None:
      print(time.strftime('%X'))
      print(await bar())
      print(await foo())
      print(time.strftime('%X'))

  asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between:

```
asyncio.create_task(async_fun())
```

and

```
await asyncio.create_task(async_fun())
```

The second one waits for the task to finish before going forward, so you're scheduling foo only after bar has finished.

First create tasks then await for them:

```
foo_task = foo()
bar_task = bar()
await foo_task
await bar_task
```

Or use `asyncio.gather`

```
await asyncio.gather(foo(), bar())
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that in the last snippet, when `gather` is used, the decorator isn't even needed. `gather` will automatically call `create_task` (via `ensure_future`) on its arguments.

Comment: thanks! gather seems alot more convenient to use, however it says it will deprecated/removed in future versions. I was wondering if we will have to call create_tasks in the future.

Comment: "Deprecated since version 3.8, will be removed in version 3.10: The loop parameter." That is referring to the `loop` argument, not `gather` itself.